# Symfony built-in cache vs APC

Tags: caching, symfony1, symfony-1.4, apc

I am going to optimise a symfony (1.4) project by caching.
I don't know what should I use? Is it better to cache whole pages, components, partial using symfony built-in cache or to cache sql results by APC? What are pros and cons for each one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say: use both.

You can use `Doctrine_Cache_Apc` for all Doctrine queries, and use Symfony cache on complex actions/components.

If you have a CMS, just remember to invalidate the cache so the user will see his editing "live". For example, on a save action in the CMS, you can use `sfFileCache::removePattern` to delete the cache files,then re-create cache files on-the-fly with `sfWebBrowser::get` .

Comment: Hm... why should I use apc with symfony cache. I think they should live same period so if there will be no symfony cache, there will be no apc cache. Is that true?

Comment: Actually i've never cached all pages inside a project since it usually displays realtime data. I'll vote your question up ;)